# MVC ashx handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, httphandler, ashx

I'm using MVC3 and want to create a route to an ashx file. I've created an Generic Handler with this code in:

```
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {

        var handler = new TileHandler();
        handler.ProcessRequest(requestContext);

        return handler;
    }
```

I've set a route up in the Global.asax which works fine. However my TileHandler which is an ashx page expects a HttpContext to be passed to it not a RequestContext. I can overload the method, but it obviously still wants the standard method invoked on call.

My question is therefore how can you use an ashx page passing in a RequestContext object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your TileHandler to inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler` instead.

[Example](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2007/11/18/asp-net-mvc-framework-create-your-own-iroutehandler.aspx).

Comment: Hi. Still no joy with this. I've changed it to inherit from MvcHandler but I get the error handler.RequestContext is readonly.

Comment: Are you trying to change RequestContext?